# Quick report Multiple Master detail report

Tags: delphi

---

anyone know how to make report model like this:

Table1 ->No_INV* , Total
Table2 ->No_INV**,Fruit,Price

### MyTitle

---

pls help me to solve this design report
and sql syntax for adoquery
i have make a Tquickrep with
TitleBand1
DetailBand1
SubDetailBand1

my result always like this

## No_INV      total

## Invoice001  1000

```
Apple    500
```

## Invoice001  1000

```
oranges   500
```

## Invoice002  1500

```
Grape    1000
```

## Invoice002  1500

```
Apple     500
```

im using sql syntax as dataset Tquickrep = select T1.No_Inv, T1.Total, T2.Fruit,T2.Price from T1 inner join T2 on T1.No_Inv=T2.No_Inv

i hope my result :

## No_INV    total

## Invoice001  1000

```
Apple    500
Oranges  500
```

## Invoice002  1500

```
Grape   1000
Apple    500
```

Comment: Please tell us what you have tried etc. Right now it seams like you want us to do your homework.

Comment: What relates to SQL syntax should probably be asked as a separate question.